# Join between tables in Laravel

Tags: join, laravel

I have two tables `{users, books}` .
How can I make join with `laravel` between them to get count of books read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Eloquent and your models are called Book and User with a Many-to-Many relationship between them, you could do something like:

```
Book::has(users)->count();
```

This will give you the count of all books which have at least one user associated. It will be converted to an inner join internally.

Answer (score 1):

With relationships:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
      public function books()
      {
            return $this->hasMany('Book');
      }
}


class Book extends Eloquent
{
      public function user()
      {
            return $this->belongsTo('User');
      }
}
```

Then in your code

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->books->count();
```

Comment: That get count of books that read by the first user only but I wanna the total of books that read.

Comment: so just then do Book::count()? That gives you all books as a count?

Comment: That gives all books read and not read but I wanna count of books only read.

Comment: So your "users" table is the books read? That doesnt make sense? Anyway - if it is, you can just do Users::count()?

Comment: If two users read the same book that counted 2 but I wanna number of books without repeated any book.

Comment: `User::select('book_id')->distinct()->count()`